# Music Ministry in Evangelical Free Church of America

Tags: worship, music, ministry, praise, evangelical-free

I have a desire to start a Music Ministry in an EFCA local assembly that sings to recorded Contemporary Praise and Worship music. How long should I be committed to this assembly before being allowed to exercise my gift?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic or not. It's hard to answer unless we have users from EFCA. Anyway, I'm curious what kind of gift you have. Is it singing or playing music instruments?

Comment: This site covers doctrine and practice. This is clearly practice and is sufficiently scoped. It is bordering on too localized if anything, but I think it relevant. It is generally looking for how long one can expect to wait before being hired by a church.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: ask the pastor and/or worship leader in your local church.

Long answer: The Evangelical Free Church is an association of churches, which is less binding than a true denomination.  As such, each individual church has a great deal of autonomy in the everyday workings of the local church.

My brother and my father are both pastors at EFCA churches. I have been a worship pastor at an EFCA church.

In the church where my brother and father serve, they have an extremely talented group of musicians. The pianist has a Master's degree in music. The bassist plays in a professional jazz band. The guitarist spent the first half of his life as a performing musician in a couple of well known mainstream bands.  At that church, it would be difficult to join the worship team in those positions - not because of your longevity in the church, but because the existing musicians are extremely talented and consistent.

I served as worship pastor in a much smaller church. If someone came to visit who had reasonable musical skill and was willing to play, I would bring them onto the worship team as early as the very next week.

In general, the larger the church, the more difficult it will be to join the worship team. Still, this is more of a function of your relative skill in your instrument than a function of how long you have been attending.

Also, a church will be more willing to give you a leadership position if they believe you are willing to stick around. When I moved to a new city, I began attending church immediately. I sat down with the pastor, explained my experience and why I had moved churches (because I moved for work) and was invited to join the worship team that next week.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What you said is correct. It also happened to me. After joining a church for one month, they made me the worship leader, mostly because there was no one better and the church was small.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not from EFCA, I can suggest few things.

Attend that local church for sometime, at least a month. Try to know who are the leaders. Try to talk with the members from the music team, try to have a connection with them. If you can make friendship with at least one of them, that's the easiest way to introduce yourself. If you are bold enough, talk with the pastor or the music leader and tell him/her your interest to join the team. You might have to first prove your skill to them in whatever ways necessary. Once you prove them your skill and your seriousness, the way will open itself. From my guess, it should not take more than five months to get in.

The church always need good singers and musicians. I pray that you find your way and start your music ministry soon. May God bless you.

Answer (score -1):

God has given every Christians gifts to return to the church for the benefit of other church members. To go looking for a local church in order to start some specific ministry does not reflect that - it's the wrong way round!

Instead, join a church were God is honoured and the gospel proclaimed, where people are loved and where you can serve people in a general sense. Then see what activities that church does, or would like to begin doing. If you have a passion for music it's likely that the church will have some sort of music ministry already - most churches do. But you may discover that the church has other more pressing needs, and you may discover that you have been gifted to serve the church in other ways.